# Display the same item in several categories

Tags: php, mysql

I use the following code to get information from my MySql data base in order to display items :

```
$sql = "SELECT product,size1,size2,prdname,price 
FROM multisize 
WHERE online= 'online' AND category = 'backcovers' AND campaign = '".$brand."'
ORDER BY size1 DESC, size2 DESC ";
```

Some times I have the same item that needs to be displayed in two campaigns. (ex. iphone4, iphone5)

is there any way to tell my code that this item should be displayed in those two campaigns or should i just create duplicate items ?

Comment: Use many to one mapping for campaign to product instead of one to one. Create option to add product so that it is associated to more than one campaign. also in sql use campaign IN (...)

Comment: Could you show us some tuples (rows) of what your resulting table looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `GROUP BY` clause in your query.

Comment: Consider providing an example